# Failure of python compilation with pyinstaller [ImportError: DLL load failed]

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I compiled this [project](https://github.com/AlessandroZ/LaZagne)  with pyinstaller, but when I run an exe file, I get this error

```
C:\Users\lik47\Desktop\LaZagne-master\Windows\dist>laZagne.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "laZagne.py", line 4, in 
File "c:\python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
exec(bytecode, module.dict)
File "lazagne\softwares\browsers\mozilla.py", line 13, in 
File "c:\python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
exec(bytecode, module.dict)
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\Crypto\Cipher\DES3.py", line 67, in 
File "c:\python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
exec(bytecode, module.dict)
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\Crypto\Cipher_DES3.py", line 7, in 
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\Crypto\Cipher_DES3.py", line 6, in bootstrap
ImportError: DLL load failed: ═х эрщфхэ єърчрээ√щ ьюфєы№.
[1184] Failed to execute script laZagne
```

ran on windows 10 x64

*without compilation (just from python script) it works*

Comment: You can find the minimal version of the corresponding DLL and call it externally in your application. You cannot add some DLL files directly to your application (which your application searches for the corresponding file in the system directories), instead you can change the contents of the corresponding library and redirect it to an additional file. Of course you need a starting point `from ctypes import Windll`

Comment: @dsgdfg tell me please what dll need  be added as a separate file?